# ASP.Net label text as HTML not working

Tags: asp.net, html, css

We have a FormData, its of type XML where it holds the value of the ASP:label and this label is in a  UserControl .

Now we load the form data with the label text as html as:

```
<ucTestControl.lblTestLabel><b>Test value</b></ucTestControl.lblTestLabel>
```

So I am passing the value as a HTML in this case as a bold.

But when I retrieve the value to the label "lblTestLabel" from FormData it binds the text as it is with the HTML tags as `<b>Test Value</b>`. However I need to displayed as a bold text.

WorkAround: If I go to the developer tool in browser by F12 and navigate to it I could see the HTML tags, when I right click the label element and select edit as HTML it renders properly as a bold text.

Comment: _"Please ignore the apostrophe"_ - but why are they there? You need to show us the actual code that you are using.

Comment: how do i do that if i take that it display as bold

Comment: Use the code button (`{}`) or use back ticks (`). See here http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: well i managed to edit wat i supposed to show hope that helps

Comment: @Ramaswamy - add code to your question. Phrases such as "We have a FormData" and "passing the value as a HTML" only have meaning for you.

Comment: FormData is a XML. Where it has a node <ucTestControl.lblTestLabel></ucTestControl.lblTestLabel>  and its value is <b>Test value</b>. Forget about passing the value you can assume there is a XML that contains node with values that include html tags. To get the values the XML would be read as a Dataset and the value will be assigned to the lable as a text.